# cakephp 4 cannot find a finder method

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I had a finder method called "findActive" in my CarsTable.php ,  I call it from another controller: **VehiclesController**.php :

**CarsTable**.php

```
    public function findActive(Query $query, array $options): Query
       { ..... }
```

// Controller **VehiclesController**.php

```
 $carsTable = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('cars');
 $activeCars = $carsTable->find('active');
```

Before I migrated it to cake 4 it was working fine. Any clue?

Comment: Any debug output?

Comment: Try `debug(get_class($carsTable));`. I'm guessing it's not actually your CarsTable class. Maybe because you should be using `->get('Cars')` instead?

Comment: Yeah, it was the issue, the camel case!! In cake 3 it was working fine, it seems that 4 is more sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

- Write you Model in CamelCase: TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('cars') -> TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Cars')
- Check if the namespace, .php file extension and location of the file is correct.
- Check if your query in findActive is correct (which I assume is the case) - the signature looks fine